# Can I ride a Trek Crockett (CX/gravel bike) in a road race if I have a road wheelset and tires on it?

Tags: road-bike, cyclocross

I’m looking to buy a Trek Crockett and I am wondering if I could use this bike year round, even as a race bike for road criterium.

Comment: Why not?  I doubt the race would exclude the bike.  If it has disc then they might not be allowed.

Comment: You can ride any bike anywhere, generally.  The restrictions might come from race rules, which could mandate certain physical measurement maximums/minimums, or a more-blanket "UCI compliant bikes only" type restriction.   I think a CX bike could be ideal for crit races, and any losses due to geometry or weight would be minor.

Comment: This bike (in its current edition, at least) has disc brakes, which would be the one thing that might rule it out. I'd check with the race organizers beforehand. It also has a 1x drivetrain, which might put you at a bit of a disadvantage—depending on how much money you're willing to throw at the problem, you might want to put a different cassette and/or chainring on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The bike actually has cantilever brakes that the current owner upgraded to and a Sram force 10-speed groupset in it.. the bike weighs just under 18lbs so I think the only real disadvantage would be the weight of the bike. Any other input any of you have would be appreciated!

Comment: If its a flat route, then weight won't matter that much.  If there were decent climbs then it might be more important.  Don't overthink the gear, just be comfortable with it.   Ride the race course beforehand if you possibly can, and that will hint what might need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, I raced all of last years criterium season on my Ridley X-bow (rim brake) with slick tires.

The thing you may also want to consider is your gearing, if you have a 1x you may want to use a different cassette.

Also if you your bike is disc brake equipped you may not be able to use it in some races. If you are racing in the UK then your in luck as British Cycling have recently announced there allowing of disc brakes in 2018 for road racing and crit, if you are racing somewhere else you will have to check your local stance on disk brakes.

Comment: I am used to disc with a c